How to style scrollbar in scss?
Why these styles don't work?:
body {
    background-color: $background-color;
    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
        scrollbar-width: 10px;
        background-color: $secondary-text-color;
      }
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background: $secondary-text-color;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    & {
        scrollbar-width: thin; 
        scrollbar-color: $secondary-text-color transparent; 
    }
}

Idk, It worked for some time and then suddenly stopped working.

We need to see your HTML as well. See [mcve]
